# Exporting mailboxes from a 32 bit Exchange 2007 Server

Tags: exchange-2007, export, mailbox, 32-bit

I am attempting to move my company's email (~40 mailboxes) from one domain to the other as we are redoing our internal system with new hardware, but I am having trouble.

In the original domain (abc.local), we have Exchange 2007 running on a WinServer 2008 Standard 64-bit OS, and I want to move all of the mailboxes to a WinServer 2012 R2 Hyper-V box on the new domain (def.local). My question is what is the best way to go about doing this? Since I can't use the Export-Mailbox cmdlet as it is running on a 64-bit OS, I have had to resort to exporting the mailbox to a pst from the user account on the local computer, transferring it to the new server, and importing it back into the user account.

Would it be best to just install the 32-bit Management tools and Outlook on a 32-bit server on abc.local and export them all that way? And if so, how could I go about doing that and have it configured for the current exchange database?

I haven't been able to find a definite answer yet through google, so I figured I'd ask you all.

Thanks.

Comment: That is rather time consuming for 40 users. If you used a DB recovery tool you could export psts directly from the exchange database in one go.

Comment: I agree that it would be time consuming, thus my post. Thank you for your reply, I will look into your suggestion further.

Answer (score 0):

Export a complete Exchange Mailbox Database to PST file:

```
Get-Mailbox -database "Mail\Mailbox Database" | Export-Mailbox -PSTFolderpath \\mail\PST
```

Export an AD OU's Users Mailboxes to PST file:

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "Sales" | Export-Mailbox -PSTFolderpath \\Mail\PST
```

The Export-Mailbox cmdlet exports all empty folders, special folders, and subfolders to the target location. However, to get in more detail please checkout this informative [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) from Technet which explains how to use the the Export-Mailbox cmdlet in the Exchange Management Shell to export mailbox data from one mailbox to a folder in another mailbox